# How do I define a patch globally with autouse?

Tags: python, pytest

Right now I do this in a few tests to mock a 3rd party API:

```
@patch("some.api.execute")
def sometest(
    mock_the_api, blah, otherstuff
):
    mock_the_api.return_value = "mocked response"
    my_func_that_uses_api(blah, otherstuff)
```

This works and prevents my_func_that_uses_api() (which calls the API) from making actual outbound calls. But I do this 4-5 times and will probably add more in the future. I'd like to mock this globally for all my tests.

I see in [the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html) this example:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def no_requests(monkeypatch):
    """Remove requests.sessions.Session.request for all tests."""
    monkeypatch.delattr("requests.sessions.Session.request")
```

How do I do that but with patching the API response?

I tried `monkeypatch.patch("some.api.execute")` but get error `AttributeError: 'MonkeyPatch' object has no attribute 'patch'`

Also, to add, I'm not using any classes in my pytest tests (like test cases) - I'd like to avoid uses classes in my pytests tests for now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just use:

```
from unittest import mock
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def my_api_mock():
    with mock.patch("some.api.execute") as api_mock:
        api_mock.return_value = "mocked response"
        yield api_mock

def test_something(blah, otherstuff):
    my_func_that_uses_api(blah, otherstuff)
```

The fixture lives as long as each function, so the patching is reverted at the end of each function.
Note that yielding the mock is not needed in this case, but if we want to change the mock in some test case, this gives you the possibility to access it:

```
def test_something(blah, otherstuff):
    my_func_that_uses_api(blah, otherstuff)

def test_something_else(my_api_mock, blah, otherstuff):
    my_api_mock.return_value = "other response for this test"
    my_func_that_uses_api(blah, otherstuff)
```

For completeness, without `auto-use` it would be:

```
@pytest.fixture
def my_api_mock():
    with mock.patch("some.api.execute") as api_mock:
        api_mock.return_value = "mocked response"
        yield api_mock

def test_something(my_api_mock, blah, otherstuff):
    my_func_that_uses_api(blah, otherstuff)
```

Comment: This doesnt appear to be working. if I dont @patch the test and pass in the my_api_mock to it, it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Ah sorry, messed this up - just corrected it. You have to use `with mock.patch(...) as api_mock`, while I wrote `api_mock = mock.patch(...)` instead, which makes no sense - it returns the patch function instead of the patched object.

Comment: Great answer, very detailed. Worked right out of the box. Thanks!